# Mirror github to Cloud Source Repositories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github

Can't connect for 3 days already, saing 'Failed to connect repositories'

All access already granted and i'm repository owner

Perhaps you know how to deal with that

EDIT: Bitbucked connected without any problem

Thanks in advanced

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Enabling the **sourcerepo.googleapis.com** API on the project solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshot it looks like you were trying to connect to an organization repository. I was having the same problem with organization repositories but I managed to find a workaround (though, I am not sure how reliable it is so it is not guaranteed to work):

1. Go to your Github application settings (https://github.com/settings/applications)
2. Revoke access from Google Cloud Platform
3. Add a new repository to Cloud Source Repositories with *"connect external repository"* (https://source.cloud.google.com/repo/new)
4. Select a project
5. Select Github as a provider
6. Now it still has your Github account selected but GCP has no access to your repositories. Click *"connect a different account"* (but still use the same account)
7. Grant access to your repositories (and the organization repositories)
8. Select an organization repository and *"connect selected repository"*
9. GCP should now be able to mirror the repository

Comment: This is what did it for me, thanks. I think the key part is to grant access to the organization itself when you authorize GCP again.

Comment: For point 7, I wanted to note that granting organization access is a separate click from granting access to the integration as a whole. You have to click "Grant" for each organization you'd like to mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Google's service is buggy at the moment. When you attempt to connect it does a POST. I am having same issue.

On my end it attempts to post:

Request URL:

`https://grimoire-pa.clients6.google.com/batch%24ct=multipart%2Fmixed%3B%20boundary%3Dbatch764066031442833345`

Request Method: `POST`
Status Code: `200` 
Remote Address: `172.217.15.202:443`

The response is a 503 error:

```
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-batch764066031442833345+gapiRequest@googleapis.com>

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
  }
}

--batch_C_zVap1Dhuz5adk2myfN4OrLwJOruXCd--
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, its looks like a bug. Bitbucket connected without any problem, just checked